# Save iframe to load faster

Tags: performance, iframe, load, embed

So, I'm making a website for a local water company. On the website there's a lot of iframe such as:

```
<iframe id="iframewebpage" runat="server" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://vandvaerk.smidstrup.net'.$DocumentDir_NoDot.$File.'&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:20%; overflow:hidden; z-index:1;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Because there's a lot of them, it takes a lot of time for the website to load. Is it somehow possible to save it on the server rather than loading on another server every time?

*Sorry, if bad english*

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider this option: Placing image for each iframe and when people click on the image, simply load that particular iframe. So you don't need to load all iframes at the same time the website load. 
HTML:

```
<img id="iframewebpage" src="img/someimage.jpg" data-src="iframe-src" / >
```

Jquery:

```
$("img#iframewebpage").click(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith("<iframe src="+$(this).data('src')+"></iframe>");
  $("iframe").attr({
      height: "500",
      allowfullscreen: "true",
      frameborder:"0"
  });
});
```

So the page only need to load images instead of iframe when it starts.